# "Be", "Become" or "Get"?

Tags: word-choice

Should I use "Be", "Become", "Get" in this sentence?

"Due to it being one of **a/the** few restaurants in this area, Saturday evenings can **become/get/be busy** so it is advised to pre-book by calling 0789343894."

Comment: Is that homework? If you're asking about only the second choice, maybe using regular font for the first one is a better idea.

Comment: I'd use "**the** few" and "**get** busy". "Become" and "be" aren't *wrong* but "get" works better.

Comment: Are you asking about two different word choices or only one? (Why mention **a/the**?)

Comment: What's your target readership? Where is this sentence going to be seen or heard? Spoken or read?

Comment: "…become…" is correct but too formal.

"…get…" is purely colloquial, yet a better choice there.

"… be…" is prolly the best choice, formally…

Answer (score 1):

“The” and “become”. The word “get”, in this instance, is informal and often used as a colloquialism. It also implies the beginning of an action rather than a change in the amount of frequency.

> **[get busy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/get_busy)** (third-person singular simple present ***gets busy***, present participle ***getting busy***, simple past ***got busy***, past participle (UK) ***got busy*** or (US) ***gotten busy***)
>
> 1. (*idiomatic*) Start working, usually in opposition to idleness.
>      <sub>Wiktionary</sub>

Comment: What's wrong with informality? Most native speakers I know would use "get" there.

Comment: To be honest, as a native speaker I would have chosen "be" rather than "get" or "become".